# How do I program my atmel develper board with sample program on the usb

Tags: atmel, atmelstudio

I have successfully compiled a sample program, which came with a developer board. I have also connected to the board via putty and ran the executable which was on the board from the factory. But I can not push my elf file to the board apparently because the debug/programming interface is missing. I can not figure out what the issue is. I turned off Win7's firewall, and defender before I installed the driver. Enclosed are a couple of pics; do I need to purchase a JTAG to usb cable? Right now, I am just connected to the board via the usb interface which is on the board. But the board comes with JATG, and miniJTAG. [image][image]
@DigiNinja- I have      AT97SC3205T-SDK2. Can you also comment on the firewall? Do I need to keep win firewall and defender off all along or just while I install the USB driver? 
I posted a pic of the board with all the other interfaces. 
Do I need one of [these](http://www.atmel.com/tools/ATMELSAM-ICE.aspx)
Here is a pic of Device Programming options:

@all- Thanks. I have a starting point. I need to read the docs now.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Usually you can program through the USB interface, but that may not be true for all of the dev boards. Which one do you have (model #)?

Comment: you are not using ethernet/network to get to this so firewall should have nothing to do with it.

Comment: I have the  AT97SC3205T-SDK2

Comment: I am not familiar with that board but it *probably* has a bootloader which means you would program through the USB interface. The STK500 interface could be worth trying. Why are you operating it from inside a metallic bag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user guide provides the info you need, and can be downloaded here: http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8528-TPM-I2C-SPI-Development-Kit-UserGuide.pdf

From the user guide:
"The USB bootloader remains pre-programmed in ROM memory. This bootloader may be used to either reload the TPM demonstration software images or to load the SAM4S ARM demonstration software. The kit has a JTAG connector that can be detached from the kit and connected to the mini JTAG connector on the board. This will allow the reprogramming of the SAM4S ARM."

So that means you should be able to load new software images using the pre-loaded USB bootloader. If you don't want to use the bootloader or it's been removed then you will need to use JTAG.

From the user guide: "For more advanced in-system programming techniques, the In-System Programmer SAM JTAG ICE combined with Atmel Studio® can be utilized over the provided JTAG interface port to exercise complete programming control over the processor."